# CefSharp context menu spawns in the wrong position

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp to embed Chromium into my WPF application. Currently im just doing some tests (example code below) but i've encountered a problem. When i right click, the context menu spawns in the wrong position. It seems like it doesnt include the offset of the window. For example, if i right click at `(0,0)` of the browser window, the context menu with spawn at approximately `(0,0)` on my screen instead.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="KCP_Doc_Manager.WBEditorTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
        xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        Title="WBEditorTest" Height="500" Width="1000">

    <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="wb"/>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class WBEditorTest : Window
{
    public WBEditorTest()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       wb.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += wb_IsBrowserInitializedChanged;            
    }
}

void wb_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (wb.IsBrowserInitialized)
   {
       wb.Load("http://www.google.com");
   }
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? What `DPI` are you running?

Comment: @amaitland CefSharp 51.0 and standard DPI (100% settings on windows 7) so presumably 96 dpi.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: @amaitland Yep, same thing happens in that example. I right click on the top left of the window and the context menu appears in the top left of the screen. It only happens in the wpf version though. The WinForms example works perfectly fine.

Comment: Until recently the `WPF` version didn't have a native `Context Menu`, you had to implement a custom one. That's what I'd usually recommend except that feature is broken in the latest version and needs to be fixed in `CEF`. You can try https://github.com/amaitland/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/15c4a7a7845452c190f6e44c5b7db41ccb504601 though I make no guarantees  on performance. See http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_DoMessageLoopWork.htm for more details

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for your help, ill look into implementing my own.

Comment: If you want your own custom menu handler then you'll have to roll back to `49`.

Comment: I'm still seeing this same issue in Cef 55.0 - the context menu pops up in the wrong location (relative to the screen instead of the window.) Additionally the context menu does not close if you click outside of it - it's necessary to select one of the options in order to close the menu

Comment: @PhilDennis I ended up using the less than optimal work around of using a `WinFormsHost` control and using the WinForms version instead.